# CSS properties supported by WorldPay custom css file

Tags: css, customization, worldpay

I have been going through http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/gg/paymentpagedesigner/content/manageassets.htm#Font in order to try and change the format of texts in Payment form to Upper Camel-Case(**text-transform: capitalize**). So I modified the css properties for specific elements and uploaded the **FLPI_Worldpay_Test_public.css** file as mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=294&v=xrrn1stqKAA

But its not working, is it by any chance text-transform property is not supported by them ?

Comment: Well did you get any errors regarding your uploaded CSS, as shown on that very page you linked to? If they did not support particular properties, then I’d expect to see an error message in the result saying so. If there isn’t one, then perhaps it is more likely that you did something wrong …

Comment: am getting an error, stating its a invalid property.

Answer (score 0):

For any CSS style property value to be accepted for rendering an element, it is important that it is the last change made to style property. In other words, your CSS might be getting overridden by another CSS file.

You can check if your results are present or not through the console.

[image]

This is also how you could experiment with CSS properties.

Also, you can use `text-transform: capitalize !important;` to enforce a style.

Comment: This won't help me in my scenario

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: WorldPay custom CSS doesnt support text-transform property

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that. CSS support depends on the client browser. Weren't you trying to modify CSS through your browser?

Comment: Not through console mate, please read the original question again.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Weren't you uploading an extra CSS file to a website? Video link does not work on my system. Also, what does this mean `is it by any chance text-transform property is not supported by them ?`